# php passing data with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

forgive me if this is a stupid question or has been asked a million times but I am having trouble using PHP keep in mind I am new to this language so if you guys could break it down simply that would be great.

so I have a file called createchatroom.php it takes user input and creates an SQL table with a column of usernames the main code is here:

```
$file = ("CREATE TABLE `" . $userstablename . "` (ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, username varchar(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID))");
```

and

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO " . $userstablename . " (username) VALUES ('". $users ."')";
```

I then have another file called im.php that deals with data from 2 more files get-messages.php and update-messages.php

the im.php is basically all js so I don't really know what is happening there but this could be helpful:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","update-messages.php?username=" + username + "&message=" + message,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

then the update-messages.php file is:

```
 <?php
 $db = new mysqli(connection info here);

if ($db->connect_error) {
   die("Sorry, there was a problem connecting to our database.");
}

$username = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_GET['username']));
$message = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_GET['message']));

if ($message == "" || $username == "") {
    die();
}

$result = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO messages VALUES('',?,?)");
$result->bind_param("ss", $username, $message);
$result->execute();
```

i need to set the "messages" table to "usertablename" from the createchatroom.php document and have no idea how to do that. thanks for your help.

Comment: As a general rule, you don't want normal everyday operation of your app to require database schema changes. I.e., creating a new chatroom should be done by inserting a row into a chatrooms table, not by creating a new table. Then you'd have one messages table, with a field (a foreign key) that indicates which chatroom the message belongs to.

Comment: I would also recommending using POST instead of GET when you send data. A good rule is to use GET when you're getting data and POST when you're sending data that should be handled and inserted/updated.

Comment: You should also use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually escaping the data. Especially since `stripslashes()` isn't a good way to protect yourself against SQL injections.